# Display all Building IDs in where clause joining two tables where one table does not have Building_ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables shown below. The following query returns only buildings with matching Business IDs in both columns. But I need to return all building_IDs included in my Where clause in the query below. If the Business_Id does not exist in Business table, I still need the query to return Building_Ids for the Businesses that are not in the Business table and have something like "Not Exists" for Business.[BusinessName] column.

Building Table

[image]

```
Select odb.Building.[Building_pk], odb.Business.[Business_pk], Business.[BusinessName]
From odb.Building bld
Left Join odb.Business bus
On bld.[Business_fk] = bus.[Business_pk]
Where bld.[Building_pk] 
IN 
(
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
) Order By bld.[Building_pk] Desc
```

I need to have this result set returned:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list in the `WHERE` clause has valid buildings, then you just need a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an inner join:

```
Select bld.Business_fk, odb.Business.[Business_pk],
       Business.[BusinessName]
From odb.Building bld Left Join
     odb.Business bus
     On bld.[Business_fk] = bus.[Business_pk]
Where bld.[Building_pk] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Order By bld.Business_fk Desc;
```

Comment: sorry I missed Left Join. Just updated the query. But please take a look one more time at the task and will see that it's not solving anything. The result set will only return building keys from 1 to 6, and will skip 7, 8, 9 and 10.

Comment: @enigma6205 . . . The `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` (and `ORDER BY`) columns should be from the `bld` table, not the `bus` table.